# Check when the last function

Tags: javascript, function

If i'm calling 2 or 3 times a function, like this:

```
somefunction();
somefunction();
```

How could i know when is the last time the function has been called?
i'm asking that because i want the last function to do one more thing.

Comment: What does "last time" mean?  Last time today?  Last time forever?  Last time in November?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 5):

Pass a parameter that determines whether the function should do "one more thing"

```
somefunction(false);
somefunction(true);
```

Comment: But what if it is called somewhere else?

Comment: If it's called from multiple places, and you can't predict the order in which the calls will occur, then the timer option suggested by @Guffa might work.  However, I would step back and ask if perhaps the "do one more thing" functionality should be a separate function that's triggered by some other means (e.g., page load completed, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You could set a timeout when the function is called, then the code will be called as soon as you exit from your first function returning control to the browser:

```
var timer = null;
function somefunction() {
  // do something
  if (timer == null) {
    timer = window.setTimeout(function(){
      // do one last thing
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/Fa5j3/

Answer (score 0):

**You can't know this.**

If you know how often it is called, you can count down a variable.

If you don't know how often it is called you can start a timeout and call the special function. If you call someFunction again you cancel the old timeout and start a new timeout.